# ModuleNotFoundError when installing plugin from zip

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have a plugin that I have developed for work and we have less than 10 users that will want to use it, so rather than publishing on the QGIS online plugin repository (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/), I thought I could zip the plugin directory and disseminate that instead, making use of the *'INSTALL from ZIP'* option on the plugin manager in QGIS.

I thought it would be as simple as zipping the directory containing the plugin code and simply pointing to that file, but I'm getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError':

```
Couldn't load plugin 'datacube_qgis_plugin/.git' 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datacube_qgis_plugin/' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 312, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datacube_qgis_plugin/'
```

My directory structure looks like:

```
datacube_qgis_plugin.zip 
                   |--- > datacube_qgis_plugin/ 
                                              |---> .py files etc.
```

Is there an exact method for 'zipping' a plugin for QGIS import?

**ADDITIONAL INFO** - If I exit the box displaying the error above, it then proceeds to say 'plugin installed successfully' - so why the error?

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the .git folder.

I recently got the same error because of a .idea folder which I think was a leftover from some python ide I used at some point.  You probably don't need the .git folder for distribution.